# Running h2o in R script in Azure machine learning

Tags: r, azure, h2o, azure-machine-learning-service

I know how to access packages in `R` scripts in `Azure machine` learning by either using the `Azure` supported ones or by zipping up the packages.

My problem now is that `Azure` machine learning does not support the `h2o package` and when I tried using the zipped file - it gave an `error`.

Has anyone figured out how to use `h2o` in `R` in `Azure machine` learning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So since there was no reply to my question, I made some research and came up with the following:

H2O cannot be ran in a straightforward manner in Azure machine learning embedded R scripts. A workaround the problem is to consider using an Azure created environment - specially for H2O. The options available are:

1. Spinning up an H2O Artificial Intelligence Virtual Machine solution
2. Using an H2O application for HDInsight

For more reading, you can go to: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/azure.html